# C# Client can't parse an ip addres

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, udp

so I am writing a C# client, where the user needs to type which IPv4 address to listen to an incoming connection from. However, though the program compliles, when typing any ip address, it comes back saying the IP was invalid. This is for any IP typed. I am wondering how to correctly parse the IP address typed in to RecieveIP.Text so it will read correctly? Thanks.

```
 try
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
    
                    string listenporttext = listenPort.ToString();
                    IPAddress RIP = IPAddress.Parse(RecieveIP.Text);
                    client = new Client(RIP, listenporttext);
                    
    
    
                    Console.WriteLine("Recieving information from lead computer " + RIP + " on port: " + listenPort);
    
    
                    recv = client.Receive(data);
                    string recc1 = recv.ToString();
                    string data_recieved = recc1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Recieved Command " + data_recieved);
                    if (data_recieved == "g")
```

Comment: "This is for any IP typed". Are you sure? Have you tried every possible combination of characters?

Comment: What is an example IP address that you would expect to work? What is the value of `ReceiveIP.Text` before you pass it to `IPAddress.Parse`?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Also receiving has `e` before `i`.

Comment: If you want to know the correct format of the string you pass to `IPAddress.Parse()`, as a general question, then I suggest you [RTFM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.parse?view=net-6.0). If you want us to tell you why your specific text isn't working, it sure would help if you provided the text that isn't working. Please see [ask].

Comment: I have tired 127.0.0.1, 192.168.50.140, and a few other computers ip addresses. So based on the few ips I have tried this happens. so it seems something is causing the ip address to be incorrectly read...

Comment: Cannot reproduce, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/lq0AIe. Unless `listenPort.ToString()` isn't returning what you think it is. Please give a [mcve]

Comment: This is the exact error it shows: Could not connect, please make sure port 8001 is allowed on firewall and server is listening. More detailed error will follow. System.FormatException: An invalid IP address was specified.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10022): An invalid argument was supplied.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.IPAddressParser.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 ipSpan, Boolean tryParse)
   at System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(String ipString)
   at Listener.Form1.LANListen_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in

Comment: Well I found the problem, it appears that the textbox where the ip address is typed for some reason does not register anything was typed. It's a messagebox, maybe it needs to be a special kind of textbox for an ip? I tried MessageBox.Show(RecieveIP.Text) to the catch statement and the message box came up empty....

Comment: @Theoneguy Then I suggest you close your question